# Does the .Net Framework Contain any Libraries for Monitoring Network Activity?

Tags: .net, network-programming, network-monitoring

I'd like to experiment with writing my own little monitoring/firewall app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think .Net contains anything but there is the `Network Monitor API` as described [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/netmon/archive/2008/10/29/intro-to-the-network-monitor-api.aspx), which should be possible to use from .Net using some PInvoke magic.

Actually, that link mentions a `NetmonAPI.CS` file that does the PInvoke for you...